# How to select data for particular date in linq using C#

Tags: c#

I am having List with data in the following format,

```
TF000040070004-29/08/12
TF000040070004-29/08/12
TF000040070005-29/08/12
TF000020010004-29/08/12
TF000020010007-29/08/12
TF000020010002-29/08/12
TF000010010012-29/08/12
TF000010010014-29/08/12
TF000010010014-29/08/12
TF000010010005-29/08/12
TF000010010005-29/08/12
TF000010010006-29/08/12
TF000010010002-29/08/12
TF000010010008-29/08/12
TF000010010008-29/08/12
TF000010010008-29/08/12
TF000010010008-29/08/12
```

I used the following linq query to get count, key value and min and max. Now I want to select the data for particular date.

```
var serialNumbers = from sn in code
                    group sn by sn.Substring(0, 10) into g
                    select new { Key = g.Key, 
                                 Cnt = g.Count(), 
                                 Min = g.Min(v => v.Substring(10)), 
                                 Max = g.Max(v => v.Substring(10)) };
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you expect your data to be split up? The date is obvious, but the key and the max/min numbers are not.

Comment: i no need display the date, i just want to dispaly key,count,max,min for particular date.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by "Key", "Max" & "Min"? That's not clear at all from your question.

Comment: In other words, is the "key" everything before the "-"? Or is it the first 10 characters (since you have `10` in your code). But what are the max and min values?

Comment: s, u r correct, key is 1st character, max and min is last 4 character. its just for serial number 00001-00008 for this purpose.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me. Can you tell me what figures I get out of "TF000040070004"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fail if there is no valid DateTime at the end of your string...

```
var selectionDate = new DateTime(2012,8,29);

var serialNumbers = from sn in code 
            where DateTime.Parse(
                         sn.Trim().Substring(sn.Trim().Length-8,8), 
                         new DateTimeFormatInfo {ShortDatePattern="dd/MM/yy"}) == 
                              selectionDate;
             group sn by sn.Substring(0, 10) into g 
             select new { Key = g.Key,  
                          Cnt = g.Count(),  
                          Min = g.Min(v => v.Substring(10)),  
                          Max = g.Max(v => v.Substring(10)) };
```

Comment: hi, rene, it shows the error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: I assume there is nothing more than spaces after the date?

Comment: i used  where sn.Contains(" 29/08/12"), now its working.but how to give dynamic date. like i want to assign string variable there like sn.contains(string name)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
from sn in rawData where sn.Substring(15, 8) == "29/08/12"
                   select sn;
```

You then can append your linq query (`group by` etc.) to that...

Comment: hi i tried like this, its shows empty..                                                    var serialNumbers = from sn in code
                                         where sn.Substring(15, 8) == "29/08/12"                                       
                                         group sn by sn.Substring(0, 10) into g
                                         select new { Key = g.Key, Cnt = g.Count(), Min = g.Min(v => v.Substring(10,4)), Max = g.Max(v => v.Substring(10,4)) };

Comment: Try @rene's solution. That is is bit more elegant than mine and should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need to transform your data for better manipulation.

```
var transformed = code.Select(item=>
{
    var parts = item.Split(new string[]{"-"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var keyPart = parts[0].Substring(2);
    var key = long.Parse(keyPart);
    var date = DateTime.Parse(parts[1]);
    return new KeyValuePair<long, DateTime>(key, date);
}
```

After transformation, perform the queries you want on strongly-typed data:

```
var date = DateTime.Today; // your date here
var result = transformed.Where(item => item.Value == date);
```